# Check for value in column in grouped dataframe in Julia

Tags: dataframe, julia

For a dataframe

```
using DataFrames, DataFramesMeta
df = DataFrame(x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], y = ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"])
```

I want to have a third column that checks per group in `y` whether there's **one** `x==2` such that the result looks like

```
6×3 DataFrame
 Row │ x      y       z     
     │ Int64  String  Bool  
─────┼──────────────────────
   1 │     1  a       true
   2 │     2  a       true
   3 │     3  a       true
   4 │     4  b       false
   5 │     5  b       false
   6 │     6  b       false
```

I've tried `@transform(groupby(df, :y), :z = :x == 2 ? true : false)` and the same with `@rtransform` but without luck.

Ideally, I can use the solution as part of a `DataFramesMeta.jl` `@chain` syntax.

---

**Edit**: Of course I could go the long way by using `@rtransform` and then filling up/down using `Impute` per group but I was hoping for a shortcut. Trying that as

```
using Impute
df_new = @chain df begin
    @rtransform :z = :x == 2 ? 1 : missing
    groupby(_, :y)
    @transform :z_new = Impute.locf(:z)
end
```

results in an `AssertionError: !(all(ismissing, data))` error. I guess because the `b` group only contains `missing`.

---

**Edit 2**: I now have slightly hacky solution that works but is far from ideal:

```
df_new = @chain df begin
    @rtransform :z = :x == 2 ? true : false
    groupby(_, :y)
    @transform :z = sum(:z) .> 0 ? true : false
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option:

```
df_new = @chain df begin
    @transform groupby(_, :y) :z = any(x.==2)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be:

```
julia> transform(groupby(df, :y),
  :x => (x -> any(==(2),x)) => :z)
6×3 DataFrame
 Row │ x      y       z     
     │ Int64  String  Bool  
─────┼──────────────────────
   1 │     1  a        true
   2 │     2  a        true
   3 │     3  a        true
   4 │     4  b       false
   5 │     5  b       false
   6 │     6  b       false
```

(this is essentially the same as the other solution...)